# Expected value of smallest element of descent set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, oeis

I'm drafting an [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) sequence, and I've formulated a few conjectures. I was hoping someone here could help me to prove them.

## Definition

Let the descent set of a permutation $\omega \in S_n$ be the set 
$$
  D(\omega) = \{i : \omega(i) > \omega(i + 1)\}.
$$

Let $$
  d(\omega) = \begin{cases}
    0               & \omega = \operatorname{id} \\ 
    \min(D(\omega)) & \text{else}
  \end{cases}.
$$

And let $$
  a(n) = \sum_{\omega \in S_n} d(\omega).
$$

---

## Example

For example, if the permutation (written as a word) is $$
  \omega = 4\ 3\ 7\ 1\ 6\ 5\ 2
$$

Then the descent set is $D(\omega) = \{1, 3, 5, 6\}$ because $$
  \begin{align*}
    \omega(1) = 4 &> \omega(2) = 3, \\
    \omega(3) = 7 &> \omega(4) = 1, \\
    \omega(5) = 6 &> \omega(6) = 5, \text{ and}\\
    \omega(6) = 5 &> \omega(7) = 2,
  \end{align*}
$$ and the minimal element of the descent set is $d(\omega) = \min\{1, 3, 5, 6\} = 1$.

The sequence of $a(n)$ starting at $n=1$ begins

```
0, 1, 7, 37, 201, 1231, 8653, 69273, 623521, 6235291, 68588301, 823059733, 10699776673, 149796873591, 2246953104061, 35951249665201, 611171244308673, 11001082397556403, 209020565553571981, 4180411311071439981, 87788637532500240001, 1931350025715005280463
```

---

## Question

I have proven that $$
  a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2\binom{n}{k+1}(n - k - 1)!,
$$ and I have two conjectures that I need help in proving (or disproving):

1. $a(n+1) = (n+1)a(n) + n^2$, with $a(1) = 0$.
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n!} = e - 1.$

Comment: This will be OEIS sequence A319013, but the sequence is presently a draft.

Answer (score 1):

$d(\omega)$ is overcomplicated. It's simply the  length of the strictly ascending prefix in $\omega$. However your exception of $\omega = \text{id}$ has further obfuscated things. When $\omega = \text{id}$ you should have $d(\omega) = n$ to be consistent with this observation.

When you fix your definition like this you will find this OEIS sequence already exists: [A002627](http://oeis.org/A002627). Your sequence only differs by $a(n) = \text{A002627}(n) - n$, so I don't think it warrants another entry. All your observations are also already present in the comments.

Comment: This sequence appeared in a quite natural context, for what it’s worth.

Comment: @PeterKagey I see now in the OEIS draft that you were aware of this relationship. Why did you not use the properties listed there?